# C2894 without any 'extern'

Tags: visual-c++, linkage

I have a quite simple code in C++, here it is:

```
namespace Phoenix
{
    template<typename T>
    struct Ref
    {
    private: T* _instance;
    public: inline Ref(T* instance) { ... }
    public: inline Ref(const Ref<T> &reference) { ... }
    public: inline Ref<T>& operator=(const Ref<T> &reference) { ... }
    };
}
```

This code is in a Visual 2012 C++ Library.

Now, if I try to reuse it in a final application, a C2894 error occurs saying I cannot declare a template to have a 'C' linkage. OK.

I didn't use `extern 'C'`...

Any idea ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after the last `}` but otherwise it compiles fine for me in a VS2012 project. Are you perhaps using it in a .c rather than a .cpp?

Comment: I badly copied/pasted my code, the semicolon is there.
Moreover, this code is in a .h file included in a .cpp file. Of course, the implementation is in the .h because it is a template struct.

Comment: Ok, I made my project match yours - I have the above code in a .h, which is included in a .cpp. It compiles fine, so we need to find what's different between your project and mine. Do you get the same error if you do what I did? Maybe your `#include` is inside an `extern "C"`?

Comment: I also tried to put my code in an all new solution.
And it compiled...
BUT, if the application is a Win32 Windows project created with the Win32 project Wizard 'Windows application' checked and 'Empty project' unchecked, then it gives this error.

Maybe an incompatibility with the implicit default includes ?

Comment: I see the problem now, and can fix it :-) You have defined a header `string.h` (which is a well known name) and this is being confused in the project. To avoid similar issues, I just renamed all of your headers - `string.h` to `MyString.h`, `Exception.h` to `MyException.h` and so on. After doing this and adjusting the corresponding `#include`'s, everything compiles fine.

Comment: Ok, this is a sooooo noob bug! Thank you for your help. Should we make an answer and validate it ? ( Just for the other noobs like me :p )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Roger Rowland, I fixed the bug in my solution.

I named a file `"String.h"` which uses my template struct Ref.

Since it exists another file named `<string.h>` by default in my project (from the C++ STL), the compiler took this one instead of mine and so the bug came.

A simple rename of the first one solved the problem.